# fuzzy matching an address using mysql's match against (if possible using weights for better results ranking)

Tags: mysql, select, street-address, fuzzy-search

I have a  myISAM table with `FULLTEXT` index , trying to do

```
SELECT 
    lk.id,
    lk.address
FROM 
    lk 
WHERE MATCH 
    lk.address 
AGAINST('235 regent street, london w1b 2et');
```

I get results but only the ones who got the word "london" inside, or ones who got the word "street" inside. I know that 3 `ft_min_word_len` character words aren't indexed so "235","w1b","2et" are ignored, but what about "regent" ? 
What is the STANDARD way of doing this? fuzzy matching an address.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `MATCH AGAINST('...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` , and to add `+` in front of every word.

Or use other characters like explained in:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

It needs fine tuning depending on your searched text, and how you got it.